# Oracle designer - table definition

Tags: oracle

I've added a new table definition to a project folder and then created a primary key, however when I click on the 'columns' to create a key component its telling me no mandatory columns are in the Table Definition - create one or more mandatory columns. I've gone back to table definitions but I can't see how I do this and then assign columns to the Primary key?
Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Are you asking how to use a specific tool (data definition to project folder)?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the exact error displayed

Comment: When I right click the 'Columns' folder to create a key component its telling me:"There are no mandatory columns in the Table Definition. Create one or more mandatory columns and then assign them to the Primary Key." Basically I'm trying to firstly, work out how to create a mandatory columns (is this done by changing the Table properties) and assigning the mandatory column to a primary key?

Comment: What release of Oracle Designer?